# Special characters display as ? marks

Tags: php, html, ajax, unicode, encoding

I have some special characters here:
http://209.141.56.244/test/char.php

but when I grab this file via ajax here, they show up as back ? marks:
http://209.141.56.244/test/char.html

These characters should be "ISO-8859-1 Western" but switching my browser encoding to any of the options don't help.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check for a code translation like utf-8 to ISO, this looks like a double decode.

Comment: I will not deny that my html is very messy and doesn't comply with standards, I will fix that when I get the chance. @Jared setting the .html to utf-8 didn't help

Comment: Give utf-8 a chance - it's not that complicated ; )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server sends the Ajax response as `text/html`, this makes the browser assume UTF-8 (which is the default), but your data itself is not UTF-8.

Send the Ajax response as `text/html; Charset=Windows-1252` (you're not really using ISO-8859-1) and it should work.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; Charset=Windows-1252');
```

PS: Switching the browser to another charset does not help because this affects the page itself only. Subsequent Ajax responses are still decoded according to their respective headers.

Comment: Just wondering, how do you know what the actual character set is? (I usually can fix these simply by specifying `UTF-8`.)

Comment: setting the header in the php file with your code did the trick! Thanks :)

Comment: @Jared Call it an educated guess. The OP stated ISO-8859-1 (a setting that is overridden with Windows-1252 in the user agent anyway). Setting the charset to anything that does not correspond with the actual data does not fix anything, so simply specifying UTF-8 won't magically make it OK.

Answer (score 3):

Your page return `text/html` as `Content-Type`, so the browser (and the ajax script) interpret them with a default encoding given by the current context.

In php you can force the encoding using the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function for the html version you should use apache configuration files (assuming you're using apache, otherwise see your webserver doc).

http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset says

> It is very important to always label Web documents explicitly. HTTP
>   1.1 says that the default charset is ISO-8859-1. But there are too
>   many unlabeled documents in other encodings, so browsers use the
>   reader's preferred encoding when there is no explicit charset
>   parameter.

from the same page

> **Apache**. This can be done via the [AddCharset](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/mod/mod_mime.html#addcharset) (Apache 1.3.10 and later)
>   or [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) directives, for directories or individual resources
>   (files). With [AddDefaultCharset](http://httpd.apache.org/docs-2.0/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset) (Apache 1.3.12 and later), it is
>   possible to set the default charset for a whole server. For more
>   information, see the article on [Setting 'charset' information in
>   .htaccess.](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset)