# German characters in browser appearing as "?"

Tags: php, html, browser, encoding

I am using php to get some data from MySQL and displaying it in a table. In db table, they appear just fine, but when I display them in browse, some characters (special character with two dots on top and hats) appear as "?". What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What kind of encoding did you use to store the chars? What encoding are you using in your html pages?

Comment: Character sets. Which does your database return? Which does your page specify?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Special characters display as ? marks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313125/special-characters-display-as-marks)

Comment: Is the encoding of db the coalition field? if so, it's set to latin1_swedish_ci. my webpage there's a metatag for utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the encoding of the SQL connection as well:

```
mysqli_set_chartset('utf8');
// or (not recommended though):
mysqli_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
```